# Run cloned git repositories

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android application development. I tried to clone a git repository from https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts.git . After cloning it, how should I build it and run it with eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Comment: have you tried importing it in eclipse ?

Comment: Is there any blog post explaining setting up with ADT or Android Studio for platform_packages_apps_contacts.git or platform_packages_apps_calendar.git . I am tired of trying to resolve the error messages thrown up in both ide's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the cloned project to your eclipse as Android Application and it should run!

Comment: I tried it. After building the project, I get more than 1000 errors. What's wrong?

Comment: You have to select a Target API and do you have the Android SDK installed?

Comment: Sorry if I annoy you. Which Target API should I use?

Comment: Just pick one between 7 and 17

Comment: I make a new android application project with target API17. Then I import the git repositories. But when I wish to build the project, the Project->build project was grey and I could not build it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, import the project into eclipse. From there you should be able to run and build it in eclipse.